# MSWord vba chart location

Tags: vba, ms-word

Building a Word report using vba that will include a chart. Problem is finding out how to insert chart at specific point int report. No matter what I try the chart ends up on page 1. I need it to e.g. be placed in page 2. See below for code. Works perfectly apart from chart placement

```
Public Function gbAuditReportGraphs(ByVal lAuditID As Long) As Boolean
'
' NRE 07-Oct-2017
'
' Purpose : Prototype graphs in Audit
' See also
' Mantis 2250
' https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff629397(v=office.14).aspx
' Note : This version outputs to a word document
' Mods


Dim objChart As chart
Dim chartWorkSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ssql As String
Dim chSeries As Series
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim clsAudit_ As New clsAudit
Dim clsRig_ As New clsRig
Dim bOk As Boolean
Dim vRigName As Variant

On Error GoTo eh

    ' Initialise function as false
    gbAuditReportGraphs = False

    clsAudit_.AuditID = lAuditID
    bOk = clsAudit_.mbLoad
    clsRig_.RigID = clsAudit_.RigID
    bOk = clsRig_.mbLoad
    vRigName = clsRig_.RigName

    ssql = " SELECT cl.checklistdesc" _
          & "      , COUNT(*) AS nccount " _
          & "   FROM tbltask t " _
          & "      , tblchecklist cl" _
          & "  WHERE cl.auditid=t.auditid" _
          & "    AND cl.checklistid = t.checklistid" _
          & "    AND cl.auditid = " & lAuditID _
          & "    AND t.tasktype = '" & gsO & "'" _
          & "    AND t.taskstatus>0" _
          & "  GROUP BY cl.checklistdesc" _
          & "  ORDER BY 1"

    Debug.Print "modADCForms.gbAuditReportGraphs, ssql = " & ssql

    ' Declare the Word Application and Document
   Set mobjWordApp = New Word.Application
   Set mobjWordDoc = mobjWordApp.Documents.Add
   mobjWordDoc.SetCompatibilityMode wdWord2010

    ' Add page numbers
    With mobjWordDoc.Sections(1)
      .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).PageNumbers.Add PageNumberAlignment:=wdAlignPageNumberRight, FirstPage:=True
       'Add Date
      .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.InsertBefore Format(Date, "dd-MMM-YYYY") & Chr(9) & Chr(9)
      .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphLeft
      .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Font.Name = "ForzaMedium"
      .Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Font.Size = 12
    End With

    Debug.Print "modADCForms.gbAuditReportGraphs,0"

    modADCForms.gInserttext wdStyleNormal, "Page 1", wdColorBlack
    modADCForms.gInsertPage
    modADCForms.gInserttext wdStyleNormal, "Page 2", wdColorBlack

    Debug.Print "modADCForms.gbAuditReportGraphs 1"

    Set rng = mobjWordDoc.Range

    With rng
        .Collapse wdCollapseEnd
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
        .InsertParagraphAfter
        .Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
    End With


    ' Set objChart = mobjWordDoc.Shapes.AddChart(xl3DPie, , 60, , 450, rng) -- type mismatch
    Set objChart = mobjWordDoc.Shapes.AddChart.chart
    objChart.ChartType = xlPie
    objChart.HasLegend = False

    Debug.Print "modADCForms.gbAuditReportGraphs 2"

    ' Create chart worksheet
    Set chartWorkSheet = objChart.ChartData.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
    ' Add a header
    chartWorkSheet.Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Series 1]]").FormulaR1C1 = vRigName & " Non-Conformance Distribution"

    rs.Open ssql, CurrentProject.Connection, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        i = 2
        Do While Not rs.EOF()
            chartWorkSheet.Range("A" & i).FormulaR1C1 = rs.Fields("checklistdesc")
            chartWorkSheet.Range("B" & i).FormulaR1C1 = rs.Fields("nccount")
            i = i + 1
            rs.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If
    rs.Close

    chartWorkSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Resize chartWorkSheet.Range("A1:B" & i - 1)

    ' Configure chart to show the values
    With objChart
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            .HasDataLabels = True
            .DataLabels.ShowValue = True
            .HasLeaderLines = True
            .DataLabels.ShowCategoryName = True
        End With
    End With

    ' set the fonts
    Debug.Print " Setting the fonts of the labels ..1."

    objChart.ChartArea.Font.Size = 9
    objChart.ChartArea.Font.Name = gsFontForzaMedium

    ' Set the location of the chart
    With objChart.Parent
        .Height = 450
        .Top = 60
    End With


    ' show the document
    mobjWordApp.visible = True

    ' Close the spreadsheet chart object
    objChart.ChartData.Workbook.Application.Quit

    ' Clear the objects
    Set rs = Nothing

    Set clsRig_ = Nothing
    Set clsAudit_ = Nothing

    ' Set function to status OK
    gbAuditReportGraphs = True

ex:
    Exit Function

eh:
    gError "Problem creating audit report graphs", "modADCForms", "gbAuditReportGraphs", Err, Error
    Resume ex

End Function
```

Comment: I'm assuming you have a reason for inserting the chart as a Shape rather than an InlineShape... Take a careful look at the AddChart method in the Word VBA Help or in the VB Editor Object Browser. You should see an optional last parameter `Range`. You need to specify that in order to *anchor* a Shape to a specific piece of text. Pass AddChart a Range object on the page where you want the chart to appear.

Comment: Note: It's a fine line, knowing how much code to put in your question... In this case, it's too much. It should be just enough to repro the problem, not so much that the problem gets lost in lines and lines of code...

Comment: I take the point its a bit verbose. I'll post a cut down version. BTW I've tried  Set objChart = mobjWordDoc.InlineShapes.AddChart.Chart but that just errors 438 object does not support this property or method

Comment: Dim ils as InlineShape : Set ils = mobjWordDoc.InlineShapes.AddChart(parans here) : Set objChart = ils.Chart or something along those lines - I'm not at a machine where I can test the exact syntax at the moment...

Answer (score 1):

Cindy, I have taken your value advice, and fixed it :)

1. Pass in parameter of the range

   Public Function gbAuditReportGraphs(ByVal lAuditID As Long, rng As Range) As Boolean
2. Create chart as an inline shape

   Set objChart = mobjWordDoc.InlineShapes.AddChart.Chart 
   objChart.ChartType = xlPie
3. Set the size with code such as

   With mobjWordApp.ActiveDocument
     .InlineShapes(1).Height = 450
     .InlineShapes(1).Width = 400
   End With
4. Copy and paste chart into the specified range

   objChart.Copy
   rng.Paste
5. Delete the original

   objChart.Delete

I could find no other advice on how to do this; perhaps this post will help others.

Comment: Glad you found something that worked :-) On StackOverflow, you're allowed to mark your own answer as "The Answer" by clicking the checkmark to the left. In order to help others even more, please use the [edit] link below your Answer and format the code into a code block (as in your question). You can make the explanation as comments in the code.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're copying/pasting the chart, by the way?

Answer (score 0):

One tip to make your solution more robust: Generally, you can't be sure that the InlineShape you insert is the first in the document, so `ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1)` isn't reliable. Better to declare an InlineShape object and assign the InlineShape belonging to the chart to it, so you can be sure you're working with the right InlineShape:

```
'1.Pass in parameter of the range
Public Function gbAuditReportGraphs(ByVal lAuditID As Long, _
                                    rng As Range) As Boolean
  Dim objChart as Word.Chart
  Dim objInlineShape as Word.InlineShape

  '2.Create chart as an inline shape
   Set objChart = mobjWordDoc.InlineShapes.AddChart.Chart 
   objChart.ChartType = xlPie

  '3.Set the size with code such as
  Set objInlineShape = objChart.Parent
  With objInlineShape
    .Height = 450 
    .Width = 400 
  End With

  '4.Copy and paste chart into the specified range
  objChart.Copy 
  rng.Paste

  '5.Delete the original
  objChart.Delete

End Function
```

Comment: ActiveDocument.InlineShapes(1) is sloppy I know; I'll fix that. I resorted to copy and paste because the call to set the chart directly at the range failed to compile - invalid property assignment. Its been complex getting it going, and now it does I think I'll leave it as is :)